# If I have more than 1 package

Tags: android, package

How can I declare in `Manifest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to declare activities that are in different packages?  You can always provide the full path to the activity, so you could just have something like

```
<manifest . . . >
    <application . . . >
        <activity android:name="com.example.project.ActivityA" . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.project2.ActivityB" . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
        . . .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Or, if you have a root package you can declare that the Package and then use relative paths:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project". . . >
    <application . . . >
        <activity android:name=".subpackage1.ActivityA" . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".subpackage2.ActivityB" . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
        . . .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a unique package:

```
package="com.your.unique.package"
```

If you have other packages, they won't interfere or cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check APIDemos sample example, this example is all in SDK. You get the idea for that.